# Asynchronous access to object's key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I spent 3 days looking for help.
I'm new to javascript so there are a lot of limitations

I'm trying to get the values in this array, but I haven't figured out the problem yet.
Someone please help me, I thank you

```js
const data = [
    {
        "label": "★ Choose Color",
        "value": {
            "9": {
                "i": 9,
                "value": "Irish-Green",
                "label": "Irish",
                "color": "#00902a"
            }
        },
        "price": false
    },
    {
        "label": "★ Choose Size",
        "value": {
            "1": {
                "i": 1,
                "value": "M",
                "label": "M",
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        "price": {
            "1": 0
        }
    }
]
data.map((item) => {
  console.log(item.value)
  /*
  I want to get the following values:
  value,  label,  color
  */
  item.value.map((val) => {
    console.log(val)
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Nothing asychronous here. But `item.value` doesn't have a `map` method.

Comment: `for (const i in item.value) for (const key in item.value[i]) console.log(key, item.value[i][key])`

Comment: Can you change the data format? An array of objects would make more sense than an object with keys like `"9"` or `"1"`.

Comment: This is dynamic data, so I can't change it

Comment: I mean can you change the code that generates this data dynamically? Because it's unnecessarily hard to process.

Comment: I can't fix it bro, because this is data from Woocommerce api